# Copying data from a server to another server

Tags: sql, sql-server, linked-server

I have two linked servers, server A and server B.
I would like to copy the data from table 1 from server A to table 2 in server B.
I know I can select from table 1 and insert into `#TempTable` by using the following query.

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable (x,y,z) 
SELECT x,y,z
FROM table 1
```

But I have no idea on how to copy data from the `#TempTable` to table 2 in server B. I also need to copy the data from table 1 in server A to table 2 in server B every Monday. Does that mean I need to create a stored procedure?

I really appreciate if anyone can provide some advice.

Comment: Use the target table instead of `#TempTable`, eg `thatserver.somedb.dbo.TheTable`

Comment: You will need to create a stored procedure and add that stored procedure to the scheduler every Monday. Go to server B and create a linked server over there and do the rest there like `insert into tableOnServer2 select * from [linkedserverA].[yourDB].[dbo].[table]`

Comment: @UsmanShahid there's no need to write a stored procedure, it's just a convenience. One could write the query directly into a SQL Server Agent T-SQL step

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes agreed, the stored procedure is convenient for comments and pretty codes while in the steps query looks so messy.. but you are right it's just a convenience

Comment: I tried with your query and this is what I obtained
`Msg 7202, Level 11, State 2, Line 3
Could not find server B in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.` @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: Which means you haven't added that linked server yet. Have you checked the docs? Have you added that server to begin with? [Create Linked Servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) shows how to create a linked server and query it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  I checked with `exec sp_linkedservers` on server A. The server B is shown in the output table.

Comment: Did you check the docs? It shows how to query tables. You won't get any other answer - you have to use a four-part name that includes the server name, database, schema and table name. And the error says the linked server doesn't exist. Perhaps you mistyped the name. Perhaps you run the query on the wrong server

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  I think I found out I used a wrong server name. I used the server name which I got from right click the server properties. But was under column SRV_DATASOURCE

Answer (score 0):

When referring to a remote table, you need to use a four part table name:

> [LinkedServerName].[DatabaseName].[SchemaName].[TableName]

So for example:

```
 INSERT INTO #TempTable(x, y, z) 
 SELECT x, y, z 
 FROM ServerA.db1.dbo.TableA
```

With temp tables if you are referring to a temp table on a remote server, it will not work with local temporary tables because of scope. You have to use global temporary tables:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TableB
SELECT x, y, z
FROM ServerB.tempdb.dbo.##TempTable
```

Note the two hash symbols before the name that represent a global temporary table as opposed to local temporary table with a single hash.

To schedule an insert use a SQL Agent Job. Job can call a stored procedure or ad-hoc SQL query.